# How to create a playlist with a single php file and multiple media files?

Tags: php, file, stream, media

well I'm trying to create a great playlist of music, only using a sigle php file.

Right now, with this code I can stream a song from a single media file source:

```
<?php

  // Try and open the remote stream
  if (!$stream = fopen('http://example.com/audio.mp3', 'r')) {
    // If opening failed, inform the client we have no content
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
    exit('Unable to open remote stream');
  }

  // It's probably an idea to remove the execution time limit - on Windows hosts
  // this could result in the audio stream cutting off mid-flow
  set_time_limit(0);

  // Inform the client we will be sending it some MPEG audio
  header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');

  // Send the data
  fpassthru($stream);
  // Thanks DaveRandom

?>
```

So, the idea is almost simple: with a single php file, create a playlist. The php file streams the first song, and then inmediatly, play another one - previously set on the php file - and over and over again, with all of the sources in the php file.

Thanks.

Comment: It would probably be better to have a single php file to handle a single mp3 at a time, then use some client-side scripting to call it asynchronously (i.e. jQuery's $.get())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Streaming is realtime protocol. While php uses single http request-response protocol. 
Which means, your php won't be called automatically to play another song by the player automatically. At best, the player will stop at end of track and only when listner clicks play again, the second request will be sent.

Now you need to have way to identify second request to play another track. sessions probably don't work in non-browser based user-agents (like media players). so you can have unique id in your php query string and have a local db/etc to keep track of what was played last time.

Either way, automatic switching of tracks would need much more php code, http buffer checking and also mp3 file parsing so the last stream and attach with next stream without the next mp3 file headers/id3/etc.

Answer (score 1):

As @nomaD said you have to use a client side script, and calculate numbers of minutes for the track, then run a timer and once it reaches the time just call another php with a new track. You might need to check this http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/api/